# Create more than 1 upload image in 1 page with droparea js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using droparea js. I have 4 upload. The problem is if I want to upload image in one of the upload menu, it changes all of the 4 upload menu.

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="droparea" >
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" class="file_preview" >
                </div>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" style="display: none;" >
    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="droparea" >
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" class="file_preview" >
                </div>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" style="display: none;" >
    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="droparea" >
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" class="file_preview" >
                </div>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" style="display: none;" >
    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="droparea" >
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" class="file_preview" >
                </div>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" style="display: none;" >
<script src="js/droparea.js"></script>
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.droparea').droparea({
                url: 'server.php',
                success: function( server_return, name, uploaded_file )
                {
                    $('.droparea').after( $('<p />').html( 'File sent: <b>' + name + '</b>' ) );

                    var oFReader = new FileReader();

                    oFReader.readAsDataURL( uploaded_file );
                    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent)
                    {
                        $( '.file_preview' ).animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function(){
                            // change the image source
                            $(this)
                                .attr('src', oFREvent.target.result).animate({opacity: 1}, 'fast')
                                .on('load', function()
                                {
                                    $('.statusbar').css({
                                        width: $('.droparea').outerWidth(),
                                        height: $('.droparea').outerHeight()
                                    });
                                });

                            // remove the alert block whenever it exists.
                            $('.droparea').find('.statusbar.alert-block').fadeOut('slow', function(){ $(this).remove(); });
                        });
                    };
                }
            });
  });


  </script>
```

I want to put it on jsfiddle but I cant file the online js and css of the droparea plugin.

For the first time if I upload in second menu or anyone except the first menu, the result will be show up in first menu. So I change from `id="file-preview"` to `class="file-preview"`it show to all of them. Would you teach me how to make it can upload different image between 1 to another?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with droparea, but you probably need to create a separate instance for each, rather than a single .droparea() instance, so something like;

```
$('.droparea').each(function(){
   $(this).droparea()
});
```

You might need this:

```
$('.droparea').each(function(){
 $(this).droparea({
            url: 'server.php',
            success: function( server_return, name, uploaded_file )
            {
                $('.droparea').after( $('<p />').html( 'File sent: <b>' + name + '</b>' ) );

                var oFReader = new FileReader();

                oFReader.readAsDataURL( uploaded_file );
                oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent)
                {
                    $( '.file_preview' ).animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function(){
                        // change the image source
                        $(this)
                            .attr('src', oFREvent.target.result).animate({opacity: 1}, 'fast')
                            .on('load', function()
                            {
                                $('.statusbar').css({
                                    width: $('.droparea').outerWidth(),
                                    height: $('.droparea').outerHeight()
                                });
                            });

                        // remove the alert block whenever it exists.
                        $('.droparea').find('.statusbar.alert-block').fadeOut('slow', function(){ $(this).remove(); });
                    });
                };
            }
        })
   })
```

Comment: My answer still stands. You need to be creating 4 instances of droparea(), at the moment you are only creating one. Updated to show you the code along with yours.

Comment: i update my desciption. and i add $(this).closest('.droparea') but no change. u have any recommendation for jquery plugin that work like dropare? here their demo http://www.jqueryrain.com/?DcZAsxGN please help

Comment: sorry press submit before i finish typing. my bad

Comment: ya i used it but still change the image on all of upload menu